# Can I make Xcode auto-complete the parameters vertically?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

take UIAlertView as an example:

the default auto complete is like this:

```
[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:........message:..........delegate:.............
```

I want it to be like this:

```
[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:...
                           message:...
                          delegate:....
```

can Xcode do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uncristify:

http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This is kind of solution, but I want it actives dynamicly, I mean indent when I am typing.